# how to convert dynamic object to array in query php using code igniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, relational-database

I want to display related data that have the same ***id***. in this case I want to display a book of some id_tags that have the same value.

```
    function _booksOther($id){
    $currentId = $id;
    $tags = $this->db->query("select id_tags from t_books_tags where id_books = $currentId");

    $id_books = $this->db->query("select id_books from t_books_tags where id_tags in($tags)");

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT t.id_tags,t.tags,bt.*,b.*  
    FROM (t_tags t LEFT JOIN t_books_tags bt  ON t.id_tags = bt.id_tags) LEFT JOIN t_books b ON b.id_books = bt.id_books
    WHERE bt.id_tags in($id_books) AND bt.id_books != '$currentId' limit 0,6");
    return $query->result();
    }
```

How to convert the object into array string?

I want to get the result of my query in the model, but i get an error like this:

```
    Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string
```

Maybe someone here can help to solve my problem ? Thanks.

Comment: To convert object to array, you just have to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). But you don't return any result after query. Check that part first. [Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) is documentation how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an object in a later query string.  You need to use the object's property.  Change your IN() statement:

```
IN($id_books->id_books)
```

Cheers!

Comment: @AgungTriLaksono If you found this answer helpful please consider selecting it as the answer. EDIT: ;D